# How to reverse a String array based on it's index value

Tags: java, arrays

I want to reverse this:

```
customArray = myArray;
nameArray = new String[myArray.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
     idArray[i] = myArray.get(i).getUnitID();
     nameArray[i] = myArray.get(i).getUnitName();
}

if (sortType == SORT)
    Arrays.sort(idArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Arrays.sort(nameArray, ...);
```

I know how to reverse this by using `Arrays.sort(stringArray, Collections.reverseOrder());` but not by index value.

How can I reverse the order of my nameArray based on it's `nameArray[i]`?.. or even better, since my idArray is actually a list of unique ID's I would like to sort nameArray based on the idArray.

Comment: Nothing is reversed in your example.

Comment: Those two examples look exactly the same.

Comment: Is that how you access elements of array ?

Comment: You are just accessing the array in reverse order. You are not reversing it.

Comment: Use `Lists.reverse(stringArray);`

Comment: Both are the same arrays. Question doesnt make sense.

Comment: ooops... editing my question... my bad

Comment: What is wrong with using `Collections.reverseorder()`?  What do you mean by "based on its index value"?  using reverseOrder() *will* reverse the indices (or really the elements)

Comment: ok ok... I jumped headfront without beying thorough. I have edited my answer to better reflect my question.

Comment: @sebster: Do you mean that you have two arrays, and want to sort them in a way, that both indexes move the same?

Comment: @jlordo Actually, what I would need is to sort the nameArray based on the idArray. The idArray is a list of unique ID's and the second one is a list with names for those Unique ID's.

Comment: @sebster: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution to your problem is to use an OOP approach. After all, Java is an OOP Language. So instead of having two arrays:

```
int[] unitID
String[] unitName
```

which you can't sort in a way that the indexes stay corresponding, write a class `Unit` that implements `Comparable<Unit>` and use one array:

```
Unit[] units
```

then

```
Arrays.sort(units);
```

will do the job.

---

You would need your own class:

```
public class Unit implements Comparable<Unit> {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    // Constructor

    // Methods

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Unit other) {
        // sorts by id
        return this.id - other.id;
        // to sort by name, use this:
        // return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: aha.. so the int[] unitID is actually the index and the String[] is my nameArray. Can you provide a small code snippet... I'm not very familiar with the syntax for custom comparators.

Comment: the thing is that my idArray[i] == nameArray[i] so that's why I was thinking it's easier to reverse the nameArray based on it's index.

Comment: @sebster: No, there will be no more `String[]` and no more `int[]`, only one `Unit[]`.

Comment: Do not compare integers using `this.id - other.id` it will fail in corner cases..

Comment: Also, I would suggest to not implement `Comparable` in `Unit`. Use a `Comparator` instead - that way you can use different compare methods (for example sorting on name or any other field).

Comment: @dacwe: `Comparable<Unit>` gives a natural ordering and doesn't prevent you from using a `Comparator` when needed. Can you be more specific regarding the corner case?

Comment: Gentlemen! There's no fighting in the War Room! :)

Comment: @jlordo: Corner case: http://ideone.com/u6iom3 (negative value bigger than positive value?)

Comment: @dacwe: nice example. Although this won't happen if you only use positive numbers for IDs, what I (and hopefully every other sane person) would do. But you are right, the code should be better safe than sorry.

Comment: Indeed its nice. But... the problem is I have 2 string arrays that I populate from a database. The first 1 idArray is a list of strings used as a UID for the second one the nameArray. When sorting them by descending order based on the UID(idArray) its ordering the idArray in descending alphabetical order but the second array(nameArray) has to reorder based on the UID assigned to it.

Comment: maybe I should start another question... or reformulate this one?.. what do you prefer?

Comment: @sebster: Definitely new question. It will be downvoted probably, as this kind of question is asked almost daily. You won't be able to avoid to write your own class holding the data, as posted in my answer.

Comment: I get that. I'm not after votes here, but after knowledge. As far as writing my own class, I don't mind that at all and I understand the paradigm... my problem lies in the design pattern behind it and understanding it properly.

Comment: @sebster: Instead of populating 2 String arrays from your DB, populate a single array with elements of your own class.

Comment: @jlordo: based on your answer I managed to build a solution with custom Comparators and I must say I love the paradigm behind the Comparable interface. Now I can reuse these comparators in multiple locations with ease.

Answer (score 3):

*(Update: Now reversing an array of strings and not a list of strings.)*

Use [`Collections.reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) together with `Arrays.asList` to reverse the array.

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String[] array = {"one", "two", "three"};

    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array)); // reverses the underlying list

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // prints [three, two, one]
}
```

Comment: Based on OPs latest comments, the question has nothing to do with reversing... He wants to sort an array, and then have the same index transformation on another array.

Comment: yep... your answer actually does the same job as Arrays.sort(nameArray, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: But according to your first question it was what you wanted. So, please, if you change your question that drastically write a **new** question instead..

Comment: Yes, you are, of course, right. Note to self: Do not blindly jump headfirst into a question.

Comment: +1 to your answer as it respected the formulation of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public  void reverseString(String[] stringArray){
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
    Collections.reverse(list);
    stringArray= (String[]) list.toArray();
}

String[] yourStringArray = new String[]{"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"};

reverseString(yourStringArray);

//result would be:
//"Wednesday","Tuesday", "Monday", "Sunday"
```